# Automate task using Python Selenium. (How to import csv)

Tags: python, selenium, csv, anaconda

I've created a python script with selenium that goes to my specified website, logs in and adds an applicant with a last name, first name, and email.
What I am needing is to import a CSV file with last names, first names and emails and I need to automate this same script but using the data from the CSV file.

I need to import csv, and have the python/selenium script constantly run until all the applicants are created, then quit.
I don't know how to do this.    here is what i have so far that works, just missing the loop and import csv..

```
!pip install selenium
!pip install webdriver_manager
!pip install bs4

from selenium import webdriver                             
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())  
driver.get("https://newaccounttest.firstunited.test/bolts/")
sleep(2)

# Login
user_id=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/ui-view/login/div/md-content/form/div/md-input-container[1]/input")
user_id.send_keys("sfreeman")
sleep(2)
password=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/ui-view/login/div/md-content/form/div/md-input-container[2]/input")
password.send_keys("Getmoney^7")
login_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/ui-view/login/div/md-content/form/button").click()
sleep(3)

# Employee channel
employee_channel=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/ui-view/desktop/blt-tiles/button[3]")
employee_channel.click()
sleep(10)
new_workspace=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/ui-view/ui-view/blt-tiles/button[2]")
new_workspace.click()
sleep(3)

# Click plus sign 
plus_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/ui-view/ui-view/md-fab-speed-dial/md-fab-trigger/button").click()
sleep(2)
plus_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/ui-view/ui-view/md-fab-speed-dial/md-fab-actions/div[1]").click()
sleep(2)


# Enter last name , first name & hit create new applicant
last_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/md-input-container[1]/input")
last_name.send_keys("freeman")
sleep(1)
first_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/md-input-container[2]/input")
first_name.send_keys("seth")
sleep(1)
search_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/button")
search_btn.click()
sleep(2)
emailfield=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/div/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[1]/div/blt-tab/div/ng-transclude/ng-include/div/blt-tab-content/div/div/div/div[2]/ng-transclude/md-content/form/fieldset/md-whiteframe/ng-form/div/div/md-input-container[2]/input")
sleep(3)
emailfield.send_keys("sfreeman@first.net")

# i 
sleep(2)
i_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/md-content/md-list/blt-search-item/md-list-item/div[2]/blt-search-toggle/button").click()
sleep(2)
addto_workplace=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/md-content/md-list/blt-search-item/blt-search-detail/div/div/div/div/div[2]/button").click()
sleep(2)
```

Comment: Why dont you read the csv and store all the values in a dictionary and iterate through each key-value pair?

Comment: i think you should use csv.DictReader() class. see if this helps: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: I'm pretty new to python -- haven't worked with creating many custom dictionaries.    Here is my test CSV file i'm trying to pull from.  @itronic1990    Can you help
 First,Last,Email,Tax,Dob,Gender,Address,Zip,City,State,Phone,License
seth,freeman,sfreeman.firstunite.com,62765598,9/22/1959,m,5235 70th ,79424,Slaton,Texas,8067901291,39514777
kace ,james ,kjames@firstunitd.net,678674677,10/25/1980,f,5655 60th ,74555,San Antonio ,Texas,8068889989,85285446
ashley,king,aking@firstunited.com,747888999,7/10/1990,m,4444 1st street,79410,Lubbock,Texas,8067120122,90875666

Answer (score 0):

With your csv file structured like below:

```
username,first_name,surname,email
username,first_name,surname,email
```

Then your code will look like this:

```
!pip install selenium
!pip install webdriver_manager
!pip install bs4

from selenium import webdriver                             
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())  
driver.get("https://newaccounttest.firstunited.test/bolts/")
sleep(2)




# Login
def enter_details(username, first_name, surname, email):
    user_id=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/ui-view/login/div/md-content/form/div/md-input-container[1]/input")
    user_id.send_keys(username)
    sleep(2)
    password=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/ui-view/login/div/md-content/form/div/md-input-container[2]/input")
    password.send_keys("Getmoney^7") # Guessing this is a command of some kind? Won't change it.
    login_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/ui-view/login/div/md-content/form/button").click()
    sleep(3)

    # Employee channel
    employee_channel=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/ui-view/desktop/blt-tiles/button[3]")
    employee_channel.click()
    sleep(10)
    new_workspace=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/ui-view/ui-view/blt-tiles/button[2]")
    new_workspace.click()
    sleep(3)

    # Click plus sign 
    plus_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/ui-view/ui-view/md-fab-speed-dial/md-fab-trigger/button").click()
    sleep(2)
    plus_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/ui-view/ui-view/md-fab-speed-dial/md-fab-actions/div[1]").click()
    sleep(2)


    # Enter last name , first name & hit create new applicant
    last_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/md-input-container[1]/input")
    last_name.send_keys(surname)
    sleep(1)
    first_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/md-input-container[2]/input")
    first_name.send_keys(first_name)
    sleep(1)
    search_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/button")
    search_btn.click()
    sleep(2)
    emailfield=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/div/md-tabs/md-tabs-content-wrapper/md-tab-content[1]/div/blt-tab/div/ng-transclude/ng-include/div/blt-tab-content/div/div/div/div[2]/ng-transclude/md-content/form/fieldset/md-whiteframe/ng-form/div/div/md-input-container[2]/input")
    sleep(3)
    emailfield.send_keys(email)

    # i 
    sleep(2)
    i_btn=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/md-content/md-list/blt-search-item/md-list-item/div[2]/blt-search-toggle/button").click()
    sleep(2)
    addto_workplace=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/md-dialog/md-content/md-list/blt-search-item/blt-search-detail/div/div/div/div/div[2]/button").click()
    sleep(2)

with open('file.csv', 'r') as File:
    csvFile = csv.reader(File, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvFile:
        enter_details(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
```

Comment: Ok    trying now.  will let you know if I run into issues thank you

Comment: So just list the CSV header fields into def enter_details  correct?

Comment: this is the error Im getting.   I am making sure that is where my csv file is and its saying this.                                                          FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-715d30b944d2> in <module>
     54     sleep(2)
     55 
---> 56 with open('boltsemployees.csv', 'r') as File:
     57     csvFile = csv.reader(File, delimiter=',')
     58     for row in csvFile:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'boltsemployees.csv'

Comment: Is your csv file in the same directory as your python file?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('CSVProject.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
{'First': 'seth', 'Last': 'freeman', 'Email': 'sfreeman.firstunite.com', 'Tax': '62765598', 'Dob': '9/22/1959', 'Gender': 'm', 'Address': '5235 70th ', 'Zip': '79424', 'City': 'Slaton', 'State': 'Texas', 'Phone': '8067901291', 'License ': '39514777 '}
{'First': 'kace ', 'Last': 'james ', 'Email': 'kjames@firstunitd.net', 'Tax': '678674677', 'Dob': '10/25/1980', 'Gender': 'f', 'Address': '5655 60th ', 'Zip': '74555', 'City': 'San Antonio ', 'State': 'Texas', 'Phone': '8068889989', 'License ': '85285446 '}
{'First': 'ashley', 'Last': 'king', 'Email': 'aking@firstunited.com', 'Tax': '747888999', 'Dob': '7/10/1990', 'Gender': 'm', 'Address': '4444 1st street', 'Zip': '79410', 'City': 'Lubbock', 'State': 'Texas', 'Phone': '8067120122', 'License ': '90875666'}
```